# I've got 3 forms. Form2, forbutton2, and ProfileView

Tags: c#

I showed forbutton2 on a panel inside the Form2, I wanted to put a button on my forbutton2 that will show the ProfileView on panel also inside a form 2.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ProfileView myForm = new ProfileView();
  myForm.TopLevel = false;
  myForm.AutoScroll = true;
  Form2.panel4.Controls.Add(myForm);
  myForm.Show();
}
```

this is the code on the button from forbutton2 form.

These were the errors prompted in the code I used:

> Error 1: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property '`Form2.panel4`'
>   Error 2: '`Form2.panel4`' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: What is the problem here?   Welcome to SO, please take a look here  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you face any problem in the code?

Comment: How can i show the ProfileView form on Form2 using the buttons i made on the forbutton2? Sorry, I'm kinda new here on SO.

Comment: Need help please :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Form2` is class name (probably declared as `public partial Form2 : Form`) and you are trying to access its field `panel4`.
2. Second error says

   > panel4 is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Which means `Form2` has `panel4` but it does not have `public` access modifier.

If `button1_Click()` method is inside `Form2` (I believe it is) use `this.panel4.Controls.Add(myForm);`. This will eliminate both errors.

Otherwise you should get reference to `Form1` which has `panel4` inside (according to comments):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ProfileView myForm = new ProfileView();
  myForm.TopLevel = false;
  myForm.AutoScroll = true;
  var form1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Where(x => x.Name == "Name of Form1").FirstOrDefault();
  form1?.panel4.Controls.Add(myForm);
  myForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry i can't explain my problem well. I've got a button on Form2 that shows the forbutton2 Form on a panel inside Form2. Then, inside the forbutton2 Form is the button1_Click() method you just said. Now, I wanted to show another Form on the panel4 located on the Form2 using the button1_Click() method located on the forbutton2 Form. It's kinda confusing to explain, please bare with me :(

Comment: What the heck is `forbutton2`?

Comment: forbutton2 is a form sir.

Comment: forbutton2 is certainly confusing. Get the reference to the parent using Control.Parent: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Let me rephrase sir. I have 3 forms. Form1, Form2 and Form3. In my Form1 I have a button and 2 panels. When I click the button on Form1, the Form2 will be displayed in the first panel of Form1. Inside the Form2 is a button. When I clicked the button on the Form2 while it is inside the panel on Form1, I wanted to show the Form3 on the second panel of Form1. But those errors prompted when I tried to build it.

Comment: You have a button on `Form2` which is inside a panel on `Form1`. When you click the button which is on `Form2`,  `button1_Click()` method should be called and should open `Form3` in another panel on `Form1`. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly sir. I couldn't open Form3 in the panel on Form1.

Comment: Yes sir, it is on Form1. And also there is a button on Form1 that will call and open Form2 inorder for it to display in the first panel on Form1.

Comment: So you should get reference to `Form1`. Edited the answer, try if it works. If doesn't inform what happened.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Hi sir. I tried using the answer you provided. I started debugging and everything was fine. But when I click the button1_Click() method to open the Form3 on the second panel. An error is prompted. 

InvalidCastException was unhandled. Unable to cast object of type 'Form1' to type 'Form2'.

Comment: Sorry, we should use `OfType<>` instead of `Cast<>`. Try now.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Thank you sir Orkhan :D I really appreciate your help, alot. Thank you very much sir.